# GCM collapse_key not working

Tags: android, python, django, google-cloud-messaging

I have a python/django app that is sending push notifications to GCM and I can't get the `collapse_key` parameter to work. It creates a new notification for each new message instead of collapsing them. The python code looks like this:

```
  url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send'                                                                                        
  post_data = {                                                                   
      'to': mytoken,                                                                
      'collapse_key': 'myappname',                                                  
      'data': mydata                                                                
  }                                                                               
  headers = {                                                                     
      'Authorization': 'key={}'.format(GCM_API_KEY),                     
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'                                          
  }                                                                                                                                               
  requests.post(                                                                  
      url,                                                                        
      data=json.dumps(post_data),                                                 
      headers=headers)
```

The notifications go through no problem but they don't collapse. Am I doing something wrong?

The client side is a phonegap mobile app using the phonegap push notifications plugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). The plugin is handling the push notifications on the device, i'm not sure how to change the way it creates and displays them.

If anyone else is having the same issue it looks like the way to do it is to pass the `notId` parameter in `data`. Notifications with the same `notId` will replace each other.

Comment: They're not collapsing when your device is off?

Comment: Could you post the code snippet where you are creating your notifications? For your information: The collapse_key is used for collapsing notifications on the GCM-servers, if you create a new notification each time you receive a notification than that has nothing to do with the collapse_key anymore but is your mistake. And: if your device is online then there is no need for GCM to collapse because the notification can be delivered instantly (if you trigger your second notification the first one already will be removed from GCM-server because the first one is already delivered to the device)

Comment: From the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages), I think you should try to set the `collapse_key` parameter in the `headers`.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the purpose of ``collapse_key``, I didn't realize it was only for offline notifications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

collapse_key only has an effect when the device is offline, for example if my device is in aeroplane mode, and it gets sent 5 messages with the same collapse_key, the device would only get the last one when aeroplane mode is turned off.

If a device is continuously connected to GCM, then each message will arrive on your device.

It sounds like you want to set a [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.app.Notification)) on your notification, so that when a new message arrives it will replace the existing notification.

Comment: I don't see this unfortunate nuance mentioned in the FCM documentation. Do you have a citation for this information?

Comment: I finally found some official documentation (in a weird place) that (barely) affirms this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=ios#what-data-exported